# Create summary of Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a Spark Dataframe which I am trying to summarise in order to find overly long columns:

```
// Set up test data
// Look for long columns (>=3), ie 1 is ok row,, 2 is bad on column 3, 3 is bad on column 2
val df = Seq(
    ( 1, "a", "bb", "cc", "file1" ),
    ( 2, "d", "ee", "fff", "file2" ),
    ( 3, "g", "hhhh", "ii", "file3" )
    ).
    toDF("rowId", "col1", "col2", "col3", "filename")
```

I can summarise the lengths of the columns and find overly long ones like this:

```
// Look for long columns (>=3), ie 1 is ok row,, 2 is bad on column 3, 3 is bad on column 2
val df2 = df.columns
    .map(c => (c, df.agg(max(length(df(s"$c")))).as[String].first()))
    .toSeq.toDF("columnName", "maxLength")
    .filter($"maxLength" > 2)
```

If I try and add the existing filename column to the map I get an error:

```
val df2 = df.columns
    .map(c => ($"filename", c, df.agg(max(length(df(s"$c")))).as[String].first()))
    .toSeq.toDF("fn", "columnName", "maxLength")
    .filter($"maxLength" > 2)
```

I have tried a few variations of the `$"filename"` syntax.  How can I incorporate the `filename` column into the summary?

| columnName | maxLength | filename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| col2 | 4 | file3 |
| col3 | 3 | file2 |

The real dataframes have 300+ columns and millions of rows so I cannot hard-type column names.

Comment: Are you reading the DataFrame from a file source (i.e csv, parquet, etc)?
If yes, then you can use the [`input_file_name()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name.html) function

Comment: Hi @Guy, yes I'm reading from parquet and have already used `input_file_name()` to add the filename to the dataframe.  The dataframe has a column called `filename` at the point I am attempting to summarise, but I don't know how to add it to the map summary.

Comment: Any view @thebluephantom?

Comment: Any view @blackbishop?

Comment: Any view @mck? .

Answer (score 1):

@wBob does the following achieve your goal?

1. group by file name and get the maximum per column:

```
    val cols = df.columns.dropRight(1) // to remove the filename col
    val maxLength = cols.map(c => s"max(length(${c})) as ${c}").mkString(",")
    print(maxLength)
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp")
    val df1 = spark
      .sql(s"select filename, ${maxLength} from temp group by filename")
    df1.show()`
```

With the output:

```
+--------+-----+----+----+----+
|filename|rowId|col1|col2|col3|
+--------+-----+----+----+----+
|   file1|    1|   1|   2|   2|
|   file2|    1|   1|   2|   3|
|   file3|    1|   1|   4|   2|
+--------+-----+----+----+----+
```

2. Use subqueries to get the maximum per column and concatenate the results using union:

```
    df1.createOrReplaceTempView("temp2")
    val res = cols.map(col => {
      spark.sql(s"select '${col}' as columnName,  $col as maxLength, filename from temp2 " +
        s"where $col = (select max(${col}) from temp2)")
    }).reduce(_ union _)
    res.show()
```

With the result:

```
+----------+---------+--------+
|columnName|maxLength|filename|
+----------+---------+--------+
|     rowId|        1|   file1|
|     rowId|        1|   file2|
|     rowId|        1|   file3|
|      col1|        1|   file1|
|      col1|        1|   file2|
|      col1|        1|   file3|
|      col2|        4|   file3|
|      col3|        3|   file2|
+----------+---------+--------+
```

Note that there are multiple entries for `rowId` and `col1` since the maximum is not unique.

There is probably a more elegant way to write it, but I am struggling to find one at the moment.

Comment: Yeah seems to work with smaller dataset, just testing it with the bigger one.  I too was hoping there was a more elegant way but whatever works : )

Comment: Thanks @Guy, I have upvoted.  I'm just holding out to see if we get something more elegant but that has helped me move forward - much appreciated.

Comment: happy to help @wBob, I'll try to spend some time later today to see if I come up with a better solution

Comment: This kind of led me to this:  `val cols = df.columns.filterNot(_.equals("filename"))

df.cache()
val res = cols.map(col => {
    spark.sql(s"WITH cte AS ( SELECT filename, '${col}' AS columnName,  MAX(LENGTH($col)) AS maxLength FROM tmp WHERE GROUP BY filename) SELECT * FROM cte WHERE maxLength > 2")
}).reduce(_ union _).groupBy("filename", "columnName").max("maxLength").as("maxLength")

res.show()` which is similar to how I'd do it in SQL but it makes me think for a 300 column table it would do 300 scans, whereas I'm not sure about the map verision, just don't know how to add filename.

Answer (score 1):

Pushed a little further for better result.

```
df.select(  
 col("*"), 
 array( // make array of columns name/value/length
  (for{ col_name <- df.columns  } yield 
   struct(
    length(col(col_name)).as("length"),
    lit(col_name).as("col"),
    col(col_name).cast("String").as("col_value")
   )  
  ).toSeq:_* ).alias("rowInfo") 
 )
 .select(
  col("rowId"),
  explode( // explode array into rows
   expr("filter(rowInfo, x -> x.length >= 3)") //filter the array for the length your interested in
  ).as("rowInfo") 
 )
 .select(
  col("rowId"),
  col("rowInfo.*") // turn struct fields into columns
 )
 .sort("length").show

+-----+------+--------+---------+
|rowId|length|     col|col_value|
+-----+------+--------+---------+
|    2|     3|    col3|      fff|
|    3|     4|    col2|     hhhh|
|    3|     5|filename|    file3|
|    1|     5|filename|    file1|
|    2|     5|filename|    file2|
+-----+------+--------+---------+
```

Comment: Interesting approaches @MattAndruff - I will try them out with my larger dataset.  Thank you.

Comment: how did it work on the larger dataset?

Comment: More checking for me to do Matt - will get back to you.

Comment: What did you end up using?

Answer (score 0):

It might be enough to sort your table by total text length.  This can be achieved quickly and concisely.

```
df.select( 
  col("*"), 
  length( // take the length
    concat(   //slap all the columns together
      (for( col_name <- df.columns ) yield col(col_name)).toSeq:_*  
    )
  )
  .as("length") 
)
.sort( //order by total length
  col("length").desc
).show()
+-----+----+----+----+--------+------+
|rowId|col1|col2|col3|filename|length|
+-----+----+----+----+--------+------+
|    3|   g|hhhh|  ii|   file3|    13|
|    2|   d|  ee| fff|   file2|    12|
|    1|   a|  bb|  cc|   file1|    11|
+-----+----+----+----+--------+------+
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but it needs to be at column level.  Basically a column is ok up to 4,000 characters but not above and we need to identify them.  The total width isn't necessarily a good indicator of that unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting an array[struct] it will sort on the first field first and second field next.  This works as we put the size of the sting up front.  If you re-order the fields you'll get different results. You can easily accept more than 1 result if you so desired but I think dsicovering a row is challenging is likely enough.

```
df.select(  
  col("*"), 
  reverse( //sort ascending
    sort_array( //sort descending
      array( // add all columns lengths to an array
        (for( col_name <- df.columns ) yield struct(length(col(col_name)),lit(col_name),col(col_name).cast("String")) ).toSeq:_* )
    )
  )(0) // grab the row max
  .alias("rowMax") )
  .sort("rowMax").show
+-----+----+----+----+--------+--------------------+
|rowId|col1|col2|col3|filename|              rowMax|
+-----+----+----+----+--------+--------------------+
|    1|   a|  bb|  cc|   file1|[5, filename, file1]|
|    2|   d|  ee| fff|   file2|[5, filename, file2]|
|    3|   g|hhhh|  ii|   file3|[5, filename, file3]|
+-----+----+----+----+--------+--------------------+
```